# Dar límite a un registro de SQL

Tags: java, sql

¿Es posible hacer que un registro tenga uso restringido luego de ciertos usos? El caso es que estoy haciendo programa que es sobre una base de datos de una biblioteca y quiero que el aval pueda utilizarse un máximo de 5 veces.

Aquí la parte del código del registro del usuario:

```
try{
    Connection net=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Biblioteca?&useSSL=false", "root", "");
    Statement stmt=net.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Clientes(Id, Nombre, Apellidos, Ocupación, Dirección, Correo, Teléfono, Identificación, `Nombre Aval`, `Apellidos Aval`) Values(NULL,'"+textField.getText()+"','"+textField_1.getText()+"','"+textField_2.getText()+"','"+textField_3.getText()+"','"+textField_4.getText()+"','"+textField_5.getText()+"','"+textField_13.getText()+"','"+textField_6.getText()+"','"+textField_7.getText()+"')");
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Aval(Id, Nombre, Apellidos, Dirección, Correo, Teléfono, Ocupación, Parentesco, Identificación) Values(NULL,'"+textField_6.getText()+"','"+textField_7.getText()+"','"+textField_8.getText()+"','"+textField_9.getText()+"',"+textField_10.getText()+",'"+textField_11.getText()+"','"+textField_12.getText()+"','"+textField_14.getText()+"')");
    stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE Aval SET Usos=Usos+1 WHERE Nombre='"+textField_6.getText()+"' AND Apellido='"+textField_7.getText()+"'");
    textPane.setText("Registro exitoso.");
}catch(Exception ex){
    textPane.setText(ex.toString());
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Intenta ser mas detallado, pon mas código con lo que hayas intentado hacer, a simple vista se puede decir que con un if puedes hacer lo que se logra entender. Pero no sé, se necesita ser mas especifico o poner codigo para saber a lo que quieres llegar.

Comment: Eso se hace de manera **programática**. En tu lógica de negocio existen ciertas reglas, como el `límite de 5 veces` para el aval que comentas. Esa regla debes plasmarla al programar, utilizado lo que creas necesario. Lo más común es guardar el número de intentos en la sesión hasta llegar al límite y restringirle el acceso o uso de un recurso.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que controlar los registros con un Estado y verificar dicho estado y las reglas de negocio (en este caso que no se "use" más de 5 veces) antes de utilizarlo. 
Debes hacerlo desde el lado del manejador de base de datos porque si las reglas del negocio cambian tendrás que modificar tu código fuente teniendo que compilar y publicar nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas,
La mayoria de bases de datos
permiten crear triggers que
controlen eso.
Si quieres hacerlo desde Java,
simplemente tienes que comprobar
si se ha alcanzado el limite antes de
hacer la insercion haciendo un
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...'.
Un saludo

Answer (score -2):

Te saldria mejor que escribieras toda esa sintaxys en un procedure o procedimiento almacenado para que lo manejes como una transaccion ya que asi como lo tienes va lineal si aglo sale mal, ya insertastes o modificastes las tablas, en un procedimiento solo pedis los parametros que esperas y desarrollas toda la logica dentro de el que es lo que tu tienes, segun veo debes de hacer un count antes de ese insertado, ese count debes de guardarlo en una variable y comparar la logica que tu quieres desarrollar.

https://enreas.fandom.com/wiki/Gu%C3%ADa_Pr%C3%A1ctica_MySQL_5.1/Cap%C3%ADtulo_11:_Procedimientos_almacenados